# How to Insert Data In MYSQL Database From A For Loop As a Single Query Using Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, simple-html-dom

I have this codes below how can i insert them as a single query it really confuse me because some data are supposed to be fetched from a For Loop any idea how to accomplish this? It really confuse me by now it only insert to database one last data only.

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="tz-arb";

  $connect=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password)or die("Error cannot connect to 

  database".mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect)or die("Failed To Select Database".mysql_error());



  include('advanced_html_dom.php'); 
  $html = file_get_html('yoururl');

   //Finding Numbers of 1x2 Game
  $numcounter = count($gameone = $html->find('div[data-gamename="1X2"]'));


   foreach($html->find(".event-date") as $evdate)
   echo "Event TIME ".$evdate."<br>";

   foreach($html->find(".event-name") as $evname)
   echo "Event NAME ".$evname."<br>";

   for ($i = 0; $i < $numcounter; $i += 3){
   // Set up variables to be inserted
   $home = $html->find('div[data-gamename="1X2"]', $i);
    $draw = $html->find('div[data-gamename="1X2"]', $i + 1);
   $away = $html->find('div[data-gamename="1X2"]', $i + 2);
   echo "1 HOME ".$home."<br>";
   echo "2 DRAW ".$draw."<br>";
   echo "3 AWAY ".$away."<br>";

   // Create unique queries for each INSERT
     $query = "INSERT INTO premier_bet_football 
        (TIME, TEAMS, HOME, DRAW, AWAY) 
 VALUES ('$evdate->plaintext', '$evname->plaintext', '$home->plaintext', '$draw->plaintext','$away->plaintext')";

  // Actually execute each unique INSERT (and log output)
   if (mysql_query($query)) {
    echo "Time And Match Added To Database";
     }
    else {
     echo "RECORD NOT ENTERED SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
     echo mysql_error();
     }

     }


    $html->clear();
     ?>
```

These are the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be inserting information directly from the HTML DOM itself. Considering your insert is outside of your loops, only the last value for `$home`, `$draw` and `$away` will get inserted. To remedy this, you need to insert into the database **inside** a loop.

In your three loops, you are essentially simply offsetting the index. This can be done inside a single loop by using an **addition** at the end of each variable assignment instead:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numcounter; $i += 3){

  // Event name and date
  $evdate = $html->find(".event-date")[$i]
  echo "Event TIME ".$evdate."<br>";
  $evname = $html->find(".event-name")[$i]
  echo "Event NAME ".$evname."<br>";

  // Set up variables to be inserted
  $home = $html->find('div[data-gamename="1X2"]', $i);
  $draw = $html->find('div[data-gamename="1X2"]', $i + 1);
  $away = $html->find('div[data-gamename="1X2"]', $i + 2);

  // Create unique queries for each INSERT
  $query = "INSERT INTO premier_bet_football 
            (time, teams, home, draw, away) 
     VALUES ('$time->plaintext', '$eventname->plaintext', '$home->plaintext', '$draw->plaintext', '$away->plaintext')";

  // Actually execute each unique INSERT (and log output)
  if (mysql_query($query)) {
    echo "Time And Match Added To Database";
  }
  else {
    echo "RECORD NOT ENTERED SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
    echo mysql_error();
  }

}
```

Also, I **strongly** recommend switching to either **[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**, as the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and outright [**removed as of PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). You should also look into **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** to prevent against MySQL Injection.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, a little question again what about this       `foreach($html->find('.event-date') as $time)
     echo $time->plaintext;
     echo "<br>";
  foreach($html->find('.event-name') as $eventname)
     echo $eventname->plaintext;
     echo "<br>";` are they going to be inside For Loop also? @Obsidian Age

Comment: @Wilson -- Probably not. In those loops you are just logging output, and you're using a **different count** to run the loop over (the number of events, as opposed to the number of `div[data-gamename="1X2"]`). Assuming those two are the **same** number, then sure, you can combine the loops :) One thing that definitely **should** be in the loop though is the actual query execution, which I forgot to include. I've updated my answer to correct this now :)

Comment: Thanks much for the clarification, the code worked well but why in `Event Date` and `Event Name` data that are sent to database is only value for every record i mean all records that are sent will have a single Event Name and Event Date but with `$HOME` `$DRAW` & `$AWAY` are sent with no any problem where am i wrong i have updated the entire code above you might check and tell me where am wrong, And i have added the echo thing to make sure the iteration works great. @Obsidian Age

Comment: The problem with your `Event Date` and `Event Name` is that you weren't inserting directly after changing the assignment, so were assigning **over** the old values, **then** inserting. They do in fact need to be **inside the same loop as the insert**. I've **updated** my answer to include it in the loop. Notice that they're no longer a `foreach` -- I'm instead using the same index from `$numcounter` to index. You **may** slightly have to tweak the variable assignment if the counts are different, but you should hopefully get the concept :)

Comment: In this code `// Event name and date
  $evdate = $html->find(".event-date")[$i]
  echo "Event TIME ".$evdate."<br>";
  $evname = $html->find(".event-name")[$i]
  echo "Event NAME ".$evname."<br>";` Does the `$i` be incremented by 3 because now they enter few data different from the actual source and the `Event Date` still entered as static value in all rows.

Comment: As I said, you may need to modify it a bit to suit. Unfortunately I can't calculate exactly how it should correlate to `$i` without you stating exactly how many `.event-name` classes you have, and also how many `div[data-gamename="1X2"]` you have. But you would need to either subtract or add **based on** the difference between those two. Afraid I can't be any more specific than that, but hopefully that will correct it for you.

Comment: Yes you are right it must be divide i think because the number of elements keep on increasing and decreasing time to time, let me settle and find out i will give you a feedback. @Obsidian Age

Comment: It worked i had to divide by 3 :-) :-) :-) Be blessed to save my time @Obsidian Age